# Regex na função Find() no python

Tags: python, regex

Preciso utilizar uma regex na função `Find()` no Python por exemplo, se eu utilizar dentro de um *loop* :

```
arq = open("arquivo.txt","rb")
var = arq.readline()        
a = var.find("abc.*def")
```

Ele vai estar procurando na linha "abc alguma coisa(.*) def" em todas as linhas do arquivo, beleza

Só que agora eu tenho duas variáveis contendo uma *string* cada, eu preciso chamar a função `Find()` com "Var1 .* Var2", ou seja procurar Var1 + qualquer coisa + Var2

```
Var1 = "abc"
Var2 = "def"
arq = open("arquivo.txt","rb")
var = arq.readline() 

a = var.find(Var1 ".*" Var2) //DESSA FORMA NÃO FUNCIONA
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar como posso fazer esse tipo de busca na linha contendo regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a função `find()` não dá, mas podes fazer o seguinte:

```
import re
var1 = "abc"
var2 = "def"
var = 'abc1dois3quatro5def' # aqui e o conteudo do teu ficheiro, arq.readline() 
match = re.compile('{}(.*?){}'.format(var1, var2)).search(var)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(1)) # 1dois3quatro5
else:
    print('nada encontrado em {}'.format(var))
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/gmLFJ1)

Pelo que percebi em conversa comentada está a usar python 2.6, então faz assim:

```
import re
var1 = "abc"
var2 = "def"
var = 'abc1dois3quatro5def'
match = re.compile('%s(.*?)%s' % (var1, var2)).search(var)
if match is not None:
    print match.group(0) # abc1dois3quatro5def
else:
    print 'nada encontrado em ' +var
```

Comment: Tive o seguinte retorno:     match = re.compile('{}(.*?){}'.format(var1, var2)).search(var)
ValueError: zero length field name in format, utilizando o seu código.

Comment: Já sei o problema, acho que estás usar python 2.6 ou inferior @MaurícioSalin , vou acrescentar uma solução para ti

Comment: Minha versão é 2.6.6 talvez seja este o problema, não tenho permissão para atualizar, se trata de um código em ambiente corporativo.

Comment: Não há problema, vamos fazer funcionar @MaurícioSalin

Comment: @MaurícioSalin, testa este: http://ideone.com/F4FsWr

Comment: Deu certo, porem percebe que esta removendo var1 e var2, preciso exatamente isso só que ao contrário, preciso achar a linha que possui var1 .* var2 e imprimir ela.

Comment: Ha ok então coloca "...match.group(0)" @MaurícioSalin , ou aopaga só o 1 e deixa vazio. Está resolvido (;

Comment: Vamos supor que eu tenho uma linha "pqrstuvxz" e outra linha "abc1234556def", preciso verificar as duas linhas porém imprimir somente a que possui abc.*def

Comment: Isso mesmo, eu já tinha posto .group(0), era somente pra deixar claro, caso alguém precisa da mesma solução futuramente, obrigado @Miguel

Comment: tivemos um segundo problema, ao imprimir match.group(0) teoricamente era pra imprimir a linha toda, mas só ta imprindo até a segunda variavel

Comment: Ha ok, então é melhor colocares uma nova pergunta @MaurícioSalin , porque aqui não posso responder a isso que é completamente diferente desta questão... Vou trabalhando num solução para te ajudar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50368/discussion-between-mauricio-salin-and-miguel).